# PHP Converting PDF's to images -dUseCropBox

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick, ghostscript

I'm trying to convert a PDF to an image and I need to make sure that the -dUseCropBox parameter is specified for when calling Ghostscript. Can this be done?

```
convert "/var/www/vhosts/site.co.uk/httpdocs/uploads/source_pdf/PP4SDpdf.pdf" -resize 500X500 "/var/www/vhosts/site.co.uk/httpdocs/uploads/image_pdf/SaturdayTest.jpg"
```

It works well but just need to get the Ghostscript parameter in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is it acceptable for you to run Ghostscript directly** (instead of having `convert` call it anyway) **?**

I ask, because `convert` does not do the PDF => JPEG conversion by itself. It calls Ghostscript as its 'delegate' to do the job. So for `convert` to work you need to have access to a functional Ghostscript installation on that system anyway... .

But how to add custom parameters to `convert`s commandline to pass them through to Ghostscript's commandline isn't easy to figure out. Ghostscript's commandline isn't exactly easy either, but at least it is fully [documented at a well-known place](http://svn.ghostscript.com/doc/current/) (see *Use.htm*, *Devices.htm* and *Ps2pdf.htm* there).

Here is a command that would convert your input PDF to a series of JPEGs (one file for each PDF page). I'm assuming Windows -- for Linux just replace the `^` by `\` and `gswin32c.exe` by `gs`:

```
gswin32c.exe ^
  -o "d:/path with spaces/to/output/dir/input_page_%03d.jpeg ^
  -sDEVICE=jpeg ^
  -dJPEQ=95 ^
  -r720 ^
  -g5000x5000 ^
  -dUseCropBox=true ^
  "d:/path/to/input.pdf"
```

**Explanation:**

- `-dJPEGQ` sets the JPEG quality. Accepts integer values in the range `0..100`. Higher values create bigger files... (Ghostscript's default for JPEGQ is set to 75.)
- `-r720` sets a (rather high) resolution of 720dpi. Higher values create bigger files... (Ghostscript's default for its jpeg output device would be 72dpi.)
- `-g5000x5000` gives the file dimension in *pixels*. (Note: when decreasing the `-r...` value you MUST also accordingly decrease the `-g...` value to keep the same dimension in userspace inches or mm.)

You could also add `-dPDFFitPage=true` if that is useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

The switch for imagemagick (the convert-command) is:

```
-define pdf:use-cropbox=true
```

see http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/#ps_reading